# Неактивные поля для ввода данных Stripe, Woocomerce

Tags: woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему поля для ввода данных не активны? Stripe, Woocomerce
Я верстку не менял, подключил woocommerce, добавил в настройках ключ, и все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно выполнить все действия шаг за шагом как в документации
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/#section-2